# How to unit test methods that construct a string?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I have a method which constructs a string from `List`. I want to test the method with a unit test. What's a good way to test that method?

I need to use the database to get matchList. I don't know how to use a mock object to do that.

```
public class File_IO
{
    private string _rootDirectory;
    private string _taskName;

    private File_IO()
    {

    }

    public File_IO(string rootDirectory, string taskName)
    {
        _rootDirectory = rootDirectory;
        _taskName = taskName;

    }

    public string RootDir
    {
        get { return _rootDirectory; }
    }

    public string TaskName
    {
        get { return _taskName; }
    }

    public string constructString()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        string pipe = "|";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        bool isFirst = true;

        IList matchList = new List<string> { "*.Ext","*.ext" };

        // Iterate over the results and construct the string.
        foreach (var item in matchList)
        {
            if (!isFirst)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(pipe);
            }

            isFirst = false;
            stringBuilder.Append(item);
        }

        result = stringBuilder.ToString();
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: `constructString()` always returns the same result and has no dependencies - I'm not sure what other tests you plan to have except one that checks it produces the only one valid result. Very unclear what you have problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunit is a pretty popular framework to do unit testing in C#. http://nunit.org/

Use nuget to install it and create your test cases.
It'll look more or less like this:

```
[Test]
public static void TestFile_IO()
{
    var expectedString = "what ever is supposed to come out of the method";
    var result = new File_IO.constructString();
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedString, result)
}
```

Comment: ICriteria crit = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Table));
            crit.Add(Restrictions.Eq("ColumnName", "someExtension"));
            IList matchList = crit.List();  Do you know how to handle this unit test if matchList is retrieved from oracle database using n hibernate.

Comment: I haven't worked with n hibernate before, not sure what the ICriteria is for. It looks like you're adding a criteria that you want to restrict results based on a the value of a columnName. If my guess is right you would run this and make sure the set of results does not contain anything that matches your restrictions. Just a guess though.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use Microsoft Fake assembly to mock/get data directly without touching database?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand question correctly or not...
May be you need something like this:

```
interface IRepository
{
    List<string> GetList();    
}

class Repository
{
    List<string> GetList() { return /*Query database here*/ ;}
}

public class File_IO
{
    private IRepository _repository;

    private File_IO(IRepository repository)
    {
         _repository = repository;
    }

    public string constructString()
    {
         IList matchList = _repository.GetList();
         .........................
         return result;
    }
}
```

In this case you will be able to test this using one of mock frameworks (Moq, NSubstitute). Example below use NSubstitute.

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    var repositoryMock = Substitute.For<IRepository>();
    repositoryMock.GetList().Returns(new List<string> {"str1", "str2"});
    var f_io = new File_IO(repositoryMock);

    var result = f_io.constructString();

    Assert.AreEqual("Expected string", result);
}
```